# Does PHP Monolog catch messages that would otherwise go to /var/log?

Tags: logging, laravel-4, centos7, monolog

I'm trying to figure out if Monolog is meant to be a replacement for Nginx and Apache logs. So if I use Monolog, which I am in Laravel, would I still need to set the following configuration parameters:

Nginx:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/barney-is-cool.net-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/barney-is-cool.net-error.log;
```

Httpd:

```
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/hulk-is-cool.net-access-log
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hulk-is-cool.net-error-log
```

Hope my question is clear enough, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MonoLog sits on top of laravel, so it will only log what happen within the framework.

Apache logs are in a different layer, apache logs will log the request and response (code, response length, etc.)

If you wish to log what could happen on Apache you should use the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives and pipe the output to an script that send such lines to your log repository using MonoLog

I have something like

```
    ErrorLog "|/usr/local/sbin/apache_error"
    CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/apache_syslog" syslog
```

Hope this helps you